# Sci-fi movie with sonar weaponry that caused ear bleeding

Tags: story-identification

I remember watching a film when I was younger. It looked like it was from the ‘80s. I can’t remember *any* scenes other than this particular one.

There are group of rebel-like people in a cave-like setting. Some opposing faction breaches the location with what I can only describe as a sonar tank. This metallic machine rolls in, sets off its sonar cannon, and then people start running around, including one human character clutching his ears with blood spurting between his fingers.

I realise this is a very specific scene! Any ideas what this movie could have been?

Answer (score 7):

I know this already has an answer, but there is no confirmation as of now and the description of the scene remembered me too much one from [Battle Beyond the Stars](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080421/), starred by a very young (1980) George Peppard.

[image: Movie poster]

In it, the bad guy threatens a peaceful and defenseless planet, delivers and ultimatum and withdraws(!) his fleet while he allows the population to think the offer, leaving only one ship<sup>1</sup>. The people in the planet give the only ship they have to the (apparently) most unexperienced youngster they can find so he gets them some help.

The guy leaves, escapes the "blockade" and begins searching allies and finds different oddballs that happen to have spaceships and nothing better to do than fight in another people's war, while at the same time meeting a girl and all of that stuff that usually happens when you wander the infinite space<sup>2</sup>.

The guy returns home with 5 or 6 allies, the blockader warns the baddie and the battle begins, there are fighting scenes both in space and on the planet, the later inside some kind of bunker caves. At some point a sonic tank forces the defenders to retreat but, by a happy coincidence two of the aliens are twin, psychic aliens who happen to have no ears. They defeat the tank but one (or both?) of them fall.

At [this trailer](https://youtu.be/ksJTPdNNQB4?t=64) appears the scene above related, but there is not much to see of the tank.

---

Side note: In Spanish the film was titled "Los 7 magníficos del espacio" (The Magnificent Seven from Space) so I guess there were seven heroes in the good side.

---

<sup>1</sup>All the ships are for one or two people, most.

<sup>2</sup>Except that no giant ape threw barrels at them.

Answer (score 5):

## David Lynch's Dune - 1984

[image: Dune1984]

Starring Kyle MacLachlan as Paul Atreides.

[image: PaulAtridiesDune1984]

Loosely set in Frank Herbert's Dune universe, this film is set on a desert planet Arrakis (Dune). Paul's family are sent to Arrakis by the Emperor to harvest the drug-like *Spice*. They have taken this task over from the Harkonnen who already hate the Atreides.

House Atreides have sonic weapons, they have to do something with a voice box type thing on their throats when firing them.

Eventually they are betrayed by the Harkonnen and the Emperor. Paul's father is killed, Paul and his mother escape to the desert and hide in Fremen caves located in the desert.

The Fremen wage war on the occupying Harkonnen with Paul leading them, destroying a lot of the infrastructure relating to harvesting the spice.

Towards the end they blow a hole in the Shield Mountains using Atomic weapons and rides in on sand worms using attacking the Harkonnen and Emperor's troops with the sonic weapons.

At the end Paul fights (and kills) Feyd Harkonnen, notably played by Sting.

[image: StingFight]

Other things that may make the film stand out are:

- Knife fights are common, due to shield technology
- Lasers are uncommon because of the same shield technology
- They use flying machines called *Ornithopters*
- There are giant sand worms that eat anything but which Paul learns to ride.

However it didn't have the tanks described. Have put this as an answer in case the intervening years have added extra details in your memory.

Comment: Did they have tanks? 0_o I must remember this stuff wrong.

Comment: @Gallifreyan Maybe not... maybe I'm confusing with the game :S oh well worth a shot.

Comment: Answered so quickly! Thanks! I love the Internet.

Comment: @MartinBean  -  are you sure this is the right one?! It's just I don't remember this particular scene in Dune.

Comment: @MartinBean - was this actually it? I was going to add some pictures and fluff up the answer to see if they helped aid your memory

Comment: The scene described in the question definitely does not occur in the original novel, however, the David Lynch movie took a number of liberties with the source material and I haven't watched it in a long time.  It may have happened in that movie rendition...

Comment: @Steve-O - you're right, there is a lot of discrepancies in the Lynch version, the sonic weapons for one and the way they deal with the "Wierding Way" - The SyFy mini series were closer to the novels IMO

Comment: The title to the question does sound like the OP is asking about the weirding modules, but I'm pretty sure there was no sonic tank in the movie.

Comment: @MrLister I know, didn't know if it was mis-remembered or conflated with other parts if he saw it a while back. Anyway it was worth a suggestion, it may help get to the right answer

Comment: No tanks in  the David Lynch version of "Dune"(1984), but there was a TV mini-series sometime in the 90s-2000s?

Comment: @theguest mini series was more faithful to novel and didn't have sonic weapons

Comment: It's a mystery then, because "Dune"(1984 movie) didn't have sonic tanks either.

Comment: "My name is a killing word"

Comment: Paul no longer wields the wielding module which Lynch originally intended as a Jedi weapon.